# Build a list from applying a recursive function on another list

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I have one list *a* of length (n+1):

```
a={a[0],a[1],...,a[n]}
```

I wish to build a list by applying a function f, a recursive non-linear function, that depends on the value of *a* at both indexes *i* and *(i-1)* and on the previous value of the "under construction" list. The first value of list *b* is defined as *b0*. Here is the list I would like to get:

```
b={b0,f(b0,a[0],a[1]),...,f(b[n-1],a[n-1],a[n]))}
```

The first and last element of list *a* won't change but I want to test several values of incrementation, therefore *n* (the length of vector *a*) will change.

I have tried using Table, Array, combining it with Module and I managed to call at least one specific value by its index from list *a* but I can't find a way to do the multiple manipulations as described above.

Comment: Are `a[i]` numbers? Does the function `f` return a number? Or the same type of object as `a[i]`?

Comment: both a and f are functions (that will be numbers only specific values of parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
avec = Array[a, 4, 0];
bvec = ConstantArray[b[0], Length[avec - 1]];
Do[
 bvec[[i]] = f[bvec[[i - 1]], avec[[i - 1]], avec[[i]]]
, {i, 2, Length[avec]}
]
bvec
```

> `{b[0], f[b[0], a[0], a[1]], f[f[b[0], a[0], a[1]], a[1], a[2]], 
>    f[f[f[b[0], a[0], a[1]], a[1], a[2]], a[2], a[3]]}`

Or more functional:

```
bvec2 = FoldList[f[#1, Sequence @@ #2] &, b[0], Partition[avec, 2, 1]];
bvec == bvec2
```

> True

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
Clear[a, b, f, g, bs]
g[i_] := f[b[i - 1], a[i - 1], a[i]]
bs[n_] := Range[n] // MapThread[g, {#}] & // Join[{b[0]}, #] &
bs[4]
```

Out:

```
{b[0], f[b[0], a[0], a[1]], f[b[1], a[1], a[2]], f[b[2], a[2], a[3]], 
 f[b[3], a[3], a[4]]}
```